# Is there an easy to remember way to filter `Get-NetIPAddress` knowing only part of an IP address?

Tags: windows, powershell

Recently I have been doing more networking work on Windows VM and Containers. These instances most easily offer PowerShell access for debugging network issues. I know the basic networking commands, `*-Net*`, but I am having a hard time filtering the Object based outputs. Specifically I find myself wanting to filter `Get-NetIPAddress` to just those objects that have IPAddress values in a certain subnet. This is pretty straight forward when you know the exact IPAddress (`Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -eq 127.0.0.1`) and I have seen ways to filter by subnet, but not something that is easy to remember. I'd rather not have to look this up every time or install a custom PS module. So my question is, how can you filter the output of  `Get-NetIPAddress` for IP's in a subnet in a way similar to how you know the exact IPAddress: `where IPAddress -eq 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: If the question is about doing partial matching, then you can do `Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -like '127.0.*'`. If the question is can you find an IP that belongs to a certain subnet, that is more complicated.

Comment: @AdminOfThings thank you! write it up as an answer so I can give you points.

Comment: I added it. Thanks

Comment: you can also use the `[version]` type accelerator to let you do range comparisons of IPv4 addresses. `[version]'127.0.0.1' -lt [version]'127.9.9.9'` will give you `True`. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For partial matching, you can use the `-like` or `-match` operator.

`-like` accepts [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7) matching. `*` matches any number of characters. `?` matches one of any character. `[]` contains a range of characters to match once.

```
# Matches 127.0.<anything>
Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -like '127.0.*'

# Matches 127.0.0.<one character>
Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -like '127.0.0.?'

# Matches 127.0.0.<one number between 0 and 9>
Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -like '127.0.0.[0-9]'
```

`-match` uses regex. This adds more flexibility and complexity. `.` match any character here so literal dots should be escaped with backslash.

```
# Matches 127.0.0.<one number between 0 and 9>
Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -match '127\.0\.0\.[0-9]'
# Matches 127.<any number>.<any number>.<any number>
Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -match '127\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
# Matches 127.0.<one number between 0 and 9>.<two digit number>
Get-NetIPAddress | where IPAddress -match '127\.0\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}'
```